# Problem get unstructured object - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

i am student

Why does it return undefined?
It is an object I need to perform destructuring to obtain only two values.
I can get complete array, but trying to unstructured it returns undefined.

service

```
   getLastCashMov(): Observable<CashMov> {
    const url = `${this.API_URL}/last_cashmov`
    return this.http.get<CashMov>(url)
  }
```

component

```
   getLastCashMov() {
    this.cashMovsService.getLastCashMov()
    .subscribe(({balanceARS, balanceUSD}) => 
      {  this.lastCashMovs = {balanceARS, balanceUSD};
        console.log(balanceARS, balanceUSD)
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

return

[image: return]

when using

```
  getLastCashMov() {
    this.cashMovsService.getLastCashMov()
    .subscribe((res) => 
      {  this.lastCashMovs = res;
        console.log(this.lastCashMovs)
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

return

[image]

**SOLUTION**

```
    getLastCashMov() {
    this.cashMovsService.getLastCashMov()
    .subscribe(([{balanceARS, balanceUSD}]) => 
      {  this.lastCashMovs = {balanceARS, balanceUSD};
        console.log(this.lastCashMovs)
      }, error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

SERVICE

```
  getLastCashMov(): Observable<CashMov[]> {
    const url = `${this.API_URL}/last_cashmov`
    return this.http.get<CashMov[]>(url)
  }
```

Comment: What is the *exact* response you’re getting back?

Comment: undefined, undefined

Comment: No, the response from your api call I mean (so remove the destructure and just console the response)

Comment: Either you're getting no values from your http call or you're mapping them in the wrong way. Try doing no mapping and logging the response from your http  call, i.e.
`.subscribe(value => console.log(value));`

Comment: `exports.getLastCashMov = async (req, res = response) => {


    try {
        
        // Obtener último movimiento
        const lastCashMov = await CashMov.find(element => element > 10000).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1);
        res.json(lastCashMov)
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send('Hubo un error');
    }
}`

Comment: @TotallyNewb doing it like this, I get the complete array, I only need two elements

Comment: Sigh.. we are trying to help you here. Just remove the destructure in the subscribe .subscribe( response => console.log(response))

Comment: There I modified the post, sorry if it is misinterpreted, I have basic English

Comment: Right! So try this: .subscribe(([{balanceARS, balanceUSD}])

Comment: Type 'CashMov' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
:/

Comment: Does your array contain only one element every time ?
or there is a chance to unstructured multiple item in array ?

Comment: That’s a different issue. The whole problem here is that you are actually receiving an array, not an object. So you cannot do an object destruct on an array. To fix that typing error change this: getLastCashMov(): Observable<CashMov[]>

Comment: Solved @MikeOne, very thanks bro. sorry if it is misinterpreted.

Comment: No problemo. Glad you solved it!

Comment: Btw, your original solution should work if you change the server slightly: res.json(lastCashMov[0])

Comment: @MikeOne I am using NodeJS, in a future will need to obtain the remaining data.
So on the hice from the back.
Very thanks devs

Answer (score 0):

We can't `Unstructure` array of object for some keys. we need to update and filter keys through `map` or `filter`

Here is the code :

---

```
getLastCashMov() {
this.cashMovsService.getLastCashMov()
.subscribe((responseArray) => {  
    let filteredArray = responseArray.map(item => return { balanceARS : item.balanceARS, balanceUSD: item.balanceUSD})   
    // filteredArray = [{ balanceARS : "...", balanceUSD: "..."}]
    this.lastCashMovs = filteredArray[0];
    console.log(balanceARS, balanceUSD)
  }, error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
}
```